# Non-constant loop condition not supported for while

Tags: verilog

This is my verilog code for CRC correction,

```
module cor(m,err);
input m;
output  err;
reg  [10:0]data;                    // message and zeros concatenated
reg  [7:0]poly;                     // polynomial equivalent
reg  [15:0]err;                     //xor output
reg  [3:0]cnt;                      // counter
reg  [2:0]n;                        // zeros
wire  [7:0]m;
reg  [7:0]poly1;                    // copy of polynomial equivalent
reg  [15:0]f;                       //shifted polynomial
//wire a;
reg [2:0]a;

initial a <= 3'b000;
initial cnt = 4'b1000;
//initial data <= {m,n};
initial poly1<= poly;

//always_comb
always @ (m or poly)
begin
data <= {m,n};
poly1 <= poly;
//data <= {m,n};
err <= data[7:0]^poly1;
while(!cnt[2:0] == 0)
begin
if(err == 4||5||6||7)begin
f <= poly1>>1;
cnt <=cnt-1;
err <= data^f;
err <= err<<1;
end
else if(err[7:4]== 2||3) begin
f <= poly1>>2;
cnt <= cnt-2;
err <= data^poly1;
err = err <<2;
end
else if(err[7:4]== 1) begin
f <= poly1>>3;
cnt <= cnt-3;
err <= data^poly1;
err <= err <<3;
end
else if(err[7:4]== 4'b0000)begin
f <= poly1>>4;
cnt <= cnt-4;
err <= data^poly1;
err <=err <<4;
end
else
err <= data^poly1;
end
if(err[7:4]==4'b0000)                           //checking remainder? zero
$display("no error detected");
else 
$display("error detected");
err <= data^poly1;                              // correcting error

end

endmodule
```

i am not able to synthesize xst

the error is: **Non-constant loop condition not supported for while**

here i think i cant use for loop because its not a linear increment (+1) after each iteration,(i am not wrong?)

please suggest me other approach to synthesize it !!

Thanks in advance 
Madhav (VLSI student)

Comment: 'not able to synthesize xst', What is `xst`?

Comment: This code will not even compile on a simulator. Combination logic should use blocking assignments (e.g. `rhs = lhs;`), not non-blocking (`<=`). Conditions such as `if (err == 4||5||6||7)` are illegal syntax, should be `if (err >=4 || err <=7)` or `if (err[15:2]==14'b1)`. You should always simulate before trying to synthesize.

Comment: Verilog is not a programming language, it is a hardware description language. The hardware cannot change at run time. Verilog is not a programming language. Verilog is not a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

> here i think i cant use for loop because its not a linear increment
>   (+1) after each iteration,(i am not wrong?)

You can't use your `while` loop because the number of iterations cannot be calculated at compile time: the condition to keep the loop is that `cnt[2:0]` is not equal to zero, so the number of loops to iterate (0 to 7) can only be known when the circuit is working and a value is stored into `cnt[2:0]`. Only loops that iterate a constant number of times are synthetisable, because the way XST goes for synthetising such loops is to unroll them.

> please suggest me other approach to synthesize it !!

You have to go for a `FSM` design, whose input is the current value of `cnt` and the current value of `err`.

By the way: there are a number of coding mistakes in your source code. One of them is:

`if(err == 4||5||6||7)begin`

This doesn't read as "if err is equal to four, five, six or seven do..." as you pretend.

You have to code it like this:

`if ( err == 4 || err == 5|| err == 6 || err == 7 ) begin`